# digitalocean droplet not showing after creating it

Tags: digitalocean

If I got to digitalocean and create a droplet

so, as you see I have two projects, Mi and Ne,  In the project called Mi, I currently have no droplets

[image]

Now I try to create a droplet

So I click create at the top, and choose create droplet. Then I go through all the options for creating a droplet, and the button to create droplet is activated

[image]

I click "create droplet"

And as you see it isn't showing up

[image]

I've used digitalocean in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have taken about up to 15 minutes to appear, so maybe the solution was to wait a while like up to 15 minutes!

Strange 'cos in the past it has appeared immediately.

UPDATE-
I made a support ticket with them and now it suddenly seems to work and do what it is meant to, which is that after the droplet is created, there should be a progress bar that starts for the creation of the droplet. (and it doesn't take that long to complete either, like within a minute).